# Video element prevent right click code does not work for dynamic elements.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have this piece of code `$('video').on('contextmenu', function(e) {e.preventDefault();});` to prevent the right click menu on the video tag. However it does not seem to work on dynamically added videos. Using [ilightbox](http://ilightbox.net/documentation.html#options) for the lightbox which adds the video element to the dom when one of the lighbox images is clicked. What can be done to allow this to work with dynamic elements?

Comment: if contextmenu event bubbles, use delegation...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: $("video").on("contextmenu", function(){}); is equivalent to $("video").bind("contextmenu", function(){}). If the video tag doesn't exist in the DOM at that point, you won't be adding the event handler to that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delegated event handlers :

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', 'video', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy588/1/)

Answer (score 0):

At first try to delegate event to body level:

```
$(document.body).on('contextmenu','video', function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```